# Open popup windows from commandbutton

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I'm trying to open a link in a new window but I can't. Here is my code:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Open" onclick="window.open=('/apex/newRic?id={{item.id}}','_blank'); return false;"/>
```

The `{{item.id}}` is an angular variable.

If I try to modify the code like this, it works but opens the link in the same window:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Apri" onclick="window.location=('/apex/newRic?id={{item.id}}'); return false;"/>
```

Help me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are using angular you could just  skip using the VF tag and just use a normal button or ngclick...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the wrong parameter passed in the following statement:

```
window.open=('/apex/newRic?id={{item.id}}','blank');
```

It should be '_blank' instead of 'blank'.

**Note:** Due to your browser settings, the window may just open in a new tab instead of a new window.
The workaround for it is passing one more parameter specifying height and width of the window:

```
 window.open('/apex/newRic?id={{item.id}}','_blank','height=200,width=200');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In my code there was "_blank", when I wrote the code here I was wrong... Anyway the code you give dosn't work for me, it doesn't anything: it doesn't update the page or open new tab or new window. It refresh the page but donsn't open anything.

Comment: no Js errors in the console log ?

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke SyntaxError: missing : in conditional expression but it refers to a css code.

Comment: Hey @DarkSkull, the issue is you have an = sign in between window.open and opening parenthesis! Try after removing it.

Comment: The correct statement would be:
window.open('/apex/newRic?id={{item.id}}','_blank','height=200,width=200');